# How to return the matched expression of a grep command

Tags: grep

I am trying to debug a command that I regular use to search across my file system. I have an external file that contains a list of regular expressions that I want to match against.

Example [the real file has hundreds of terms] `cat terms.txt`

`cat\|dog\|mouse\|frog\|horse`

Right now I am experiencing an issue where I believe one of my terms is causing me a headache and returning true on every line. I want to be able to figure out what term is constantly getting hit so I can go readdress it to be more accurate. I am using this in conjunction with the `strings` utility.

`find /data/*/** -type f -print0 | xargs -0 strings -f -t d | grep -w "$(terms.txt)"`

Which returns in the following format

`/data/animals/felines.txt: 6 tiger cat`

What I would like to see is something similar to where the expression that was matched in my terms.txt file be appended to the end of the line. Is this possible without building out a bash script of some sort?

`/data/animals/felines.txt: 6 tiger cat - matched expression "cat"`

Comment: Are the individual search terms in your terms.txt supposed to be fixed strings or regular expressions?  if the former, you'd probably be better off having one term per line and using `grep -F -f terms.txt -w -o`.   even if they're meant to be regexps, it would still be better to use `-f terms.txt` (again with one search term per line).  Also, why `find /data/*/**` rather than just `find /data -mindepth 2`?

Answer (score 1):

`grep`'s `-o` option won't produce exactly the output you're looking for, but it should help you find the issue; it only outputs the matching portion of each line, and if multiple portions of a line match, it outputs each portion separately (on separate lines):

```
/data/animals/felines.txt:cat
```

Comment: I tried implementing the following command with the `-o` flag `find /data/*/** -type f -print0 | xargs -0 strings -f -t d | grep -ow "$(terms.txt)"` and the results count seems much more reasonable. I think this issue might have to deal with the way `strings` pipes into `grep`. For example without the -o in the above command i get a line count of 3087960 and with the -o in the above command i get 984 (which i think is ground truth) Using it as debugging mechanism seems to produce different result counts so its hard to tell if this will help or not.